# automatically reload Kubernetes pod on consul key change

Tags: consul, consul-template

I have a consul server running on https://dev.example.com/ on which I store configurations as below:

consul key name = dev

consul key value = `some yaml data`

kubernetes configMap value `some yaml data` --> ( this is in sync with consul data )

what I want to do is as soon as I change something in `some yaml data`, the values should be automatically reflected in configMap and pod should be reloaded automatically to capture new values.

I have tried `envconsul` but it only picks keys with one value.

I tried `consul-template` but did not find any good working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/Trendyol/trendyol-consul-template-injector. It allows you to inject consul-template as a sidecar to your pod, and will generate files from templates that are provided in a ConfigMap. Your application will need to monitor this generated file, and reload itself when the file changes.

See https://medium.com/trendyol-tech/configuration-and-secret-management-with-consul-template-on-kubernetes-dcc4c6695142 for a more detailed blog post explaining why this was built and how it works.